# Bessel process conditioned to stay positive

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose the stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ with start in $X_0:=x>0$ is the solution of the SDE $$ dX_t = dB_t + \frac{\rho-1}{2X_t} \, dt $$ with $B_t$ denoting Brownian motion known as the generalized Bessel process with dimension parameter $\rho\in\mathbb R$. Let us assume we have $\rho\in (0,2)$ such that it is possible to construct the reflected Bessel process.

Can anything be said about the law of the Bessel process conditioned to never hit 0? More specifically, is there a Law of the Iterated Logarithm? (If $\rho=1$ it holds $X_t=B_t$, so the desired law is that of a 3-dimensional Bessel process. But what about general $\rho\in(0,2)$?)

Comment: See the answer posted in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395649/bessel-process-conditioned-to-stay-positive/395802#395802